# I installed some packages using pip, but it shows me that there is no such thing

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, python-import

So I made a python file that has 3 imports as shown here:[image: example]

Although when I run it says that there is no such module installed.

Comment: Do you run `pip` by just calling `pip` or `python -m pip`?

Comment: I used python -m pip install name_of_import

Comment: Make sure to use the exact same python interpreter when installing dependencies and when running your code. Basically it would be `C:\path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install NameOfSomeDependency` and then  `C:\path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\path\to\code\script.py`.

Comment: what do you mean by python interpreter

Comment: You maybe have multiple installations of Python on your computer, which means multiple `python.exe` files. Maybe you are also using "virtual environments", and for each of those there is a `python.exe` file. -- So whatever your setup is, always make sure to use exactly the `python.exe` you have in mind. One sure way to do this, is by calling the full path to that `python.exe`.

Comment: @LACORONAVIRUS try `where python` in your terminal and see if it matches with the interpreter your IDE uses

Comment: I am using the built in terminal in my interpreter. VScode